# rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'mongoid_search:index'

Tags: search, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid

Hi I am trying to do rake mongoid_search:index and it is giving me this error.

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'mongoid_search:index'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@app/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@app/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a refine search I am able to figure out my error.

In my gemset I have two versions mongoid(2.x,3.x). So, I removed the older version and added

[Mongoid Rake](https://github.com/mauriciozaffari/mongoid_search/blob/master/tasks/mongoid_search.rake) file in my lib/tasks folder solved my issue.

Comment: The above link does not exist now.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the error by adding the master to the gem, referenced from https://github.com/mauriciozaffari/mongoid_search/issues/67

gem 'mongoid_search', github: 'mauriciozaffari/mongoid_search', branch: 'master'